# Авторизация Symfony 3.0

Tags: symfony3, oauth2, аутентификация

Делаю авторизацию на Symfony, в реализации особых проблем нет, настроил проверку из базы данных, всё работает:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security::
    Delivery\AdminBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt

providers:
    user_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: DeliveryAdminBundle:User
            property: username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:    ^/admin
        provider:   user_db_provider
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
          login_path: _security_login      #login route
          check_path: _security_check      #credentials check route
          failure_path: _security_login    #failed login route
          default_target_path: a_home      #successfull login route
        logout:
          path: _security_logout           #logout route
          target: a_home                   #route to redirect after logout

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Также нужно по тому же роуту ^/admin настроить прямую авторизацию без ввода логина/пароля, а передавая в url тип авторизации - email, hash для проверки и авторизовывать в случае успешной проверки.

Здесь https://habrahabr.ru/post/134005/ описана реализация, но не могу разобраться как система будет "понимать", какой тип использовать - прямой или через форму входа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разные фаерволы для одного и того же урла сделать не получится.

Я бы сделал это следующим образом. Сделал бы отдельный "открытый" урл, на который идет пользователь с email+hash в строке запроса. Дальше можно в контроллере провалидировать этот хэш, после чего вручную создать и сохранить токен пользователя.

```
$tokenStorage = $this->get('security.token_storage');
$tokenStorage->setToken(new SomeCustomHashToken($user, $user->getRoles()));
```

После перезагрузки, система будет считать пользователя с текущей сессиией авторизированным.

Comment: Токен, я насколько понял, нужно создать самому, верно?

Comment: @Zaur да. Можешь даже использовать любой существующий токен, разницы нет. Но я предпочитаю на такие случаи создавать кастомный, чтобы сразу было понятно как именно пользователь авторизировался. Туда можно записать какую-то доп. информацию - например хэш и email (они в теории могут понадобиться в будущем).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Реализовал немного иначе, но Вы натолкнули на мысль!